# Disable Adding NEW Contact from Account Page

Tags: administration, npsp

I come to the problem. When I am creating new Account, there is possibility to add a primary contact for it. Problem is, I just want to choose from available Contacts and disable adding new in the process

( + New Contact )

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That's the default functionality Salesforce provides.

If you want to override this functionality then use Lightning Components using 
`lightning:recordEditForm`.

For more information, refer [Record Edit Form](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:recordEditForm/documentation)

Comment: Nice and do you have any specific steps how to do it? I just want to disable it and not to create my whole custom lightning page.